# asNavFor not working ngx-slick-carousel in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, slick.js

I am working on a project made in Angular 8 & want to use a third-party library such as [ngx-slick-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel) and everything is working fine but I have thumbnail carousel, where an option like `asNavFor`, see the below attributes

```
imagesSlider = {
  speed:300,
  slidesToShow:1,
  slidesToScroll:1,
  cssEase:'linear',
  fade:true,
  autoplay: true,
  draggable:true,
  prevArrow:'.client-feedback .prev-arrow',
  nextArrow:'.client-feedback .next-arrow',
  asNavFor:".client-thumbnails",
};
thumbnailsSlider = {
  speed:300,
  slidesToShow:5,
  slidesToScroll:1,
  cssEase:'linear',
  autoplay: true,
  centerMode:true,
  draggable:false,
  focusOnSelect:true,
  asNavFor:".feedback-slides .client-feedback",
  prevArrow:'.client-thumbnails .prev-arrow',
  nextArrow:'.client-thumbnails .next-arrow',
};
```

and the HTML looks like

```
<div class="feedback-slides">
   <div class="client-feedback">
        <ngx-slick-carousel 
            class="carousel" 
            #slickModal="slick-carousel" 
            [config]="imagesSlider">
            <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
                    <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
            </div>
        </ngx-slick-carousel>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="client-thumbnails">
     <ngx-slick-carousel 
        class="carousel" 
        #slickModal="slick-carousel" 
        [config]="thumbnailsSlider ">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
                <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
        </div>
    </ngx-slick-carousel>
</div>
```

as above codes not working & showing an error in the console like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSlick' of undefined

If I remove the option `asNavFor` error will disappear but thumb click doesn't work anymore.

What can I do now?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing the wrong classes in `asNavFor`. It needs to be the class name of the ngx-slick-carousel instance.

Try this and let me know.

```html
<div class="feedback-slides">
   <div class="client-feedback">
        <ngx-slick-carousel 
            class="carousel feedback" 
            #slickModal="slick-carousel" 
            [config]="imagesSlider">
            <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
                    <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
            </div>
        </ngx-slick-carousel>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="client-thumbnails">
     <ngx-slick-carousel 
        class="carousel thumbs" 
        #slickModal="slick-carousel" 
        [config]="thumbnailsSlider ">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
                <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
        </div>
    </ngx-slick-carousel>
</div>
```

```js
imagesSlider = {
  speed:300,
  slidesToShow:1,
  slidesToScroll:1,
  cssEase:'linear',
  fade:true,
  autoplay: true,
  draggable:true,
  prevArrow:'.client-feedback .prev-arrow',
  nextArrow:'.client-feedback .next-arrow',
  asNavFor:".thumbs",
};
thumbnailsSlider = {
  speed:300,
  slidesToShow:5,
  slidesToScroll:1,
  cssEase:'linear',
  autoplay: true,
  centerMode:true,
  draggable:false,
  focusOnSelect:true,
  asNavFor:".feedback",
  prevArrow:'.client-thumbnails .prev-arrow',
  nextArrow:'.client-thumbnails .next-arrow',
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="feedback-slides">
   <div class="client-feedback">
        <ngx-slick-carousel 
            class="carousel" 
            #slickModal="slick-carousel" 
            [config]="imagesSlider">
            <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" id="client-feedback" class="slide">
                    <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
            </div>
        </ngx-slick-carousel>
    </div>
</div>

thumbnailsSlider = {
  speed:300,
  slidesToShow:5,
  slidesToScroll:1,
  cssEase:'linear',
  autoplay: true,
  centerMode:true,
  draggable:false,
  focusOnSelect:true,
  asNavFor:"#client-feedback",
  prevArrow:'.client-thumbnails .prev-arrow',
  nextArrow:'.client-thumbnails .next-arrow',
};
```